# Multicolumn in toc and in section tocs in beamer

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, multicol

I have a presentation where I have section and subsection headings that are displayed at the beginning of each section/subsection. I am trying to get these to be in two columns. I have managed to get the original TOC in two-column format, but the subsequent displays of TOC at section/subsection headings do not come out in two-column. I would appreciate some help

Another issue that I am noticing is that the two-columns on the first TOC are not aligned -- the second column is higher than the first. Cant' figure out why.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[table,xcolor=pdftex,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\usepackage{multicol}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
\begin{frame}<beamer>
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[
  currentsection
]
\end{frame}
}

\AtBeginSubsection[]
{
\begin{frame}<beamer>
\frametitle{Outline}
\tableofcontents[
  currentsection,currentsubsection
]
\end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section*{Outline}
         \begin{frame}
             \frametitle{Outline}
     \begin{multicols}{2}
           \tableofcontents
     \end{multicols}
       \end{frame}

\section{Introduction -- Graph Types}

\section{Property Graph Processing}
    \subsection{Classification}
    \subsection{Online querying}
    \subsection{Offline analytics}

\section{Graph Analytics Approaches}
    \subsection{MapReduce \& Variants}
    \subsection{Classification of Native Approaches}

\section{Graph Analytics Systems}
    \subsection{Vertex-Centric BSP}
    \subsection{Vertex-Centric Asynchronous}
    \subsection{Vertex-Centric GAS}
    \subsection{Block-Centric BSP}
    \subsection{Edge-Centric BSP}

\addtocontents{toc}{\newpage}

\section{OLAP-Style Analytics}
    \subsection{Graph Summarization}
    \subsection{Snapshot-based Aggregation}
    \subsection{Graph Cube}
    \subsection{Pagrol}
    \subsection{Gagg Model}

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please fix your code and remove all these \ in front of [ and ] to make it compilable?

Comment: Sorry, don't know how they got inserted, but I think I cleaned all of them now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not use the `multicol` package with beamer, as beamer has it's own environment for columns. This way you avoid the misalignment at the top.

To make the section and subsection `toc`s also two column, repeat whatever code you use to get the global `toc` in two columns for these `toc`s.

```
\documentclass[table,xcolor=pdftex,dvipsnames]{beamer}
\usetheme{Madrid}
\usecolortheme{whale}
\beamertemplatenavigationsymbolsempty

\AtBeginSection[]{
    \begin{frame}<beamer>
        \frametitle{Outline}
        \begin{columns}[T]
            \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
                \tableofcontents[currentsection,sections=1-4]
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
                \tableofcontents[currentsection,sections=5]
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
}

\AtBeginSubSection[]{
    \begin{frame}<beamer>
        \frametitle{Outline}
        \begin{columns}[T]
            \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
                \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection,sections=1-4]
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
                \tableofcontents[currentsection,currentsubsection,sections=5]
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \frametitle{Outline}
    \begin{columns}[T]
        \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[sections=1-4]
        \end{column}
        \begin{column}{.45\textwidth}
            \tableofcontents[sections=5]
        \end{column}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction -- Graph Types}

\section{Property Graph Processing}
    \subsection{Classification}
    \subsection{Online querying}
    \subsection{Offline analytics}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}

\section{Graph Analytics Approaches}
    \subsection{MapReduce \& Variants}
    \subsection{Classification of Native Approaches}
    \begin{frame}\end{frame}

\section{Graph Analytics Systems}
    \subsection{Vertex-Centric BSP}
    \subsection{Vertex-Centric Asynchronous}
    \subsection{Vertex-Centric GAS}
    \subsection{Block-Centric BSP}
    \subsection{Edge-Centric BSP}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}
%\addtocontents{toc}{\newpage}

\section{OLAP-Style Analytics}
    \subsection{Graph Summarization}
    \subsection{Snapshot-based Aggregation}
    \subsection{Graph Cube}
    \subsection{Pagrol}
    \subsection{Gagg Model}
\begin{frame}\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this is great. I was following a suggestion to use multicol in another posting at this site, but this works great.

Comment: One thing I just noticed: this shows the TOC at section breaks, but not on subsection breaks. I can't see why, but perhaps you can see something and help? NEVER MIND PLEASE: I noticed that the second definition should be \AtBeginSubection

Comment: @ozsu Sorry for that, I forgot to change this after copy&pasting.